# does cocos2d cache texture automatically

Tags: textures, cocos2d-x

I know if we want the textures cached we can use the sharedtexture manager to cache them, but since this is on mobile platform , why don't cocos2d-x just do this for all texture loads ?

when creating sprites with images, are these textures cached as well ?

Answer (score 1):

It automatically caches for us. You can check it via Profiler to monitor for the current usage of memory, it goes up until we purgeCache manually or when memory warning kicks in then it will automatically does the job for us.